# How to set time picker at top of inline style Date picker in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uidatepicker, ios14

I have set inline style date for iOS 14. In this date picker timer picker is display at bottom. I want to display that time picker at top of inline style date picker like display in iOS default calendar app.

My app screen shot:
[image]

iOS default calendar app screen shot:
[image]

Comment: You may just create 2 date pickers, one for the date and one for the time

Comment: @TLGCodin' Thanks for answer. have you any idea about how to stop display keyboard when focus on time picker?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I suggest you will open another question about it

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` does not officially support Time Picker above the Date Picker inside an in-line `UIDatePicker`.

However, you can just create 2 Date Pickers, one for the date and one for the time, and then arrange them however you want.

This code that I made might help you:

```
let time = timePicker.date
var date = datePicker.date
date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)

let calendar = Calendar.current

var timeInterval: TimeInterval = 0
timeInterval += Double(calendar.component(.second, from: time))
timeInterval += Double(calendar.component(.minute, from: time)) * 60
timeInterval += Double(calendar.component(.hour, from: time)) * 3600

date.addTimeInterval(timeInterval)
```

Then use the variable `date` , and everything should work like in a regular date-and-time Date Picker.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Date Time Picker
extension UIViewController {
    
    func setUpDatePicker(dateFormat: String, startDate : Date,timePicker : Bool, completion: @escaping (_ selectedDate: String)->()) {
        
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.minimumDate = startDate
        
        if timePicker == true {
            
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        }
        
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            datePicker.sizeToFit()
        }

        let dateChooserAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Date", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 200)
        dateChooserAlert.view.addSubview(datePicker)
        dateChooserAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            
            // Your actions here if "Done" clicked...
            let dateformat = DateFormatter()
            if timePicker == true {
                
                dateformat.timeStyle = .medium
                completion(dateformat.string(from: datePicker.date))
            }
            else{
                
                dateformat.dateFormat = dateFormat
                completion(dateformat.string(from: datePicker.date))
            }
            
        }))
        let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateChooserAlert.view as Any, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.1, constant: 300)
        dateChooserAlert.view.addConstraint(height)
        self.present(dateChooserAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Use

self.setUpDatePicker(dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy", startDate: Date(), timePicker: false, completion: { (selectedDate) in
            

                  print(selectedDate)
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes